# Group schema settings in shopify into separate title with accordion

Tags: shopify, schema

Is it possible to create a collapsible settings in schema with Shopify

What I need is something similar to the bellow pictures to group each few settings into a collapsible accordion

[image: before]

[image: after]

Comment: Did you find a solution? I've been trying to do something similar to no avail.

Comment: No didn't find any @PabloRincon, I created blocks and added each set of changes inside a separate block